# Are there rational coefficients that hold such properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, noncommutative-algebra

I'm designing a boardgame system for which I have some properties I would like to hold, and after some trial-and-error I have found no advances on whether there is a solution to the system or not, but some interesting non-commutative diagrams of functions appeared.

To contextualize, I have four resources, call them $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$ and $R_4$. As an *action* you can use a card to exchange a resource for another. Let this *action* of using a card and exchanging $a \ R_1$ for $b \ R_2$ be a linear function $f_1: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ with a rational coefficient $m_1 = b/a$. That is, $f_1(a) = m_1 a$, for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$.

This is the full **non-commutative** diagram of functions $f_1, \ldots, f_8$ and how they relate to the resources $R_1, \ldots, R_4$:

[Image of  the **non-commutative** diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzT4f.png)

Let an $n$**-action path** starting at $R_j$ and ending at $R_k$ be a sequence of $n$ exchanges, starting at $R_j$ and ending at $R_k$. So, for example, there is a $2$*-action path* from $R_1$ onto itself; namely, $R_1 \longrightarrow_5 m_5 R_3 \longrightarrow_6 m_6 m_5 R_1$.

Finally, let an $n$*-action path* from $R_j$ onto itself **net** $x$ if, and only if, there exists an $n$*-action path* from $R_i$ onto itself such that $m_{i_n} m_{i_{n-1}} \ldots m_{i_1} = x$

---

Now onto the question itself. Are there rational coefficients $m_1, \ldots, m_8$ assigned, respectively, to the functions $f_1, \ldots, f_8$ such that, for any resource $R_j$, the following conditions are all true:

$\bullet$ Any $2$*-action path* from $R_j$ onto itself nets $4$;

$\bullet$ Any $3$*-action path* from $R_j$ onto itself nets $6$;

$\bullet$ Any $4$*-action path* from $R_j$ onto itself nets $16$.

Or, more generally, instead of netting $4$, $6$ and $9$, respectively, netting $a$, $b$ and $c$, with $a < b < c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If I have understood the rule (not clear) then $m_1 m_2=4$ and $m_1m_2m_3=6$, yes?  If so then of course $m_3=\frac 64=\frac 32$.  And then $m_2m_3=4\implies m_2=\frac 83\implies m_1=\frac {12}8=\frac 32$ .   Continuing in this way either yields a contradiction or lets you solve for all the $m_i$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Note: if I have understood the rules correctly then it is clearly impossible as we'd have $9=m_1m_2m_3m_4=4^2$.

Comment: As you have pointed out, for $9$ and $4$ it may not be possible. What if it was $16$ and $4$, for example? It would solve this problem in particular, but it's not clear to me if it would yield any other contradictions down the line.

Comment: Well, I may have it wrong.  Are you only looking at loops that start and stop at the same place?  If so then I erred in saying that $m_1m_2=4$.

Comment: You got it wrong on the indexes of $m_i$. On the picture, it would mean that $m_5 m_6 = 4 = m_6 m_5$, and also $m_1 m_2 m_6 = 6$, not $m_1 m_2 m_3$ per say.

Comment: Anyway, once the rules are clarified just wrote out all the loops involved (there really aren't many).   Solve for the $m_i$ as I was starting to do...either you hit a contradiction or you find an explicit solution.

Comment: Ok, so the only $2-$loops yield $m_5m_6=4=m_7m_8$, yes?

Comment: That is correct. As I also pointed out, perhaps it's not doable for $\{4, 6, 9\}$, but is it not possible for any $\{a, b, c\}$ such that $a < b < c \in \mathbb{Q}$? How would I go about proving that instead?

Comment: My method does not depend on the specific numbers involved.  With your numbers, though, you still get a contradiction out of the $4-$ loop as $9=(m_5m_6)^2=16$.

Comment: Note:  it is clear that there are solutions for some $a<b<c$.  Just take all the $m_i=\lambda>1$.  Then let $a=\lambda^2,b=\lambda^3,c=\lambda^4$.

Comment: That would indeed be a valid solution and would answer my game-related question fully. Would this process yield all possible solutions?

Comment: No idea.  I think you should take a crack at clarifying your question some and trying to see if you can play with the numbers to get the sort of solution you really want.

Answer (score 1):

I have found, together with @lulu, a family of answers $\{a,b,c\}$, with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$. As noted in the comment section of the main post, the set $\{4,6,9\}$ is not a solution, for $m_5 m_6 = 4$ and $m_5 m_6 m_5 m_6 =16 \neq 9$.

If we no longer ask that **any** $4$*-action path* nets $c$, and instead that only a $4$*-action path* composed of $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ and $f_4$ net $c$ (thus enabling the path $f_5 \longrightarrow f_6 \longrightarrow f_5 \longrightarrow f_6$ to not necessarily net $c$), then there is another family of solutions.

Note that every $3$*-action path* goes once, and only once, through either $f_5$, $f_6$, $f_7$ or $f_8$, and thus goes twice through either $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ or $f_4$.

Thus if $m_i = \lambda_1$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $m_j = \lambda_2$ for $j \in \{5,6,7,8\}$, then

$\bullet$ Any $2$*-action path* nets $\lambda_2 = a$;

$\bullet$ Any $3$*-action path* nets $\lambda_2 \lambda_1^2 = b$;

$\bullet$ Any $4$*-action path* nets $\lambda_1^4 = c$.

And so the set of solutions would be of the form $\{ \lambda_2^2, \lambda_2 \lambda_1^2, \lambda_1^4 \}$, for any $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 > 1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lambda_2 < \lambda_1^2$.